# Weird Bar Above Navigation

Tags: firefox

This showed up when I opened Firefox this morning. Anyone know what it is and how to remove it?

[image: weird bar with circle]

Comment: Perhaps an empty navbar or a messed up extension? Check and disable ?

Comment: tried that. I disabled all my plugins, checked all tool/nav bars -nothing.